# I got an error when measuring execution time of small code snippets

Tags: python-3.x, timeit

Here is the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html)
When I use the Command-Line Interface on Windows cmd, I got this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>
C:\Windows\system32>python3 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\timeit.py", line 362, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\timeit.py", line 315, in main
    t = Timer(stmt, setup, timer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\timeit.py", line 123, in __init__
    compile(stmtprefix + stmt, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 2
    '-.join(str(n)
                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the double quotes on the outside and the single quotes inside the expression.

```
python -m timeit "'-'.join(str(n) for n in range(100))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must likely need to escape the python code line. On the last line of the provided stack trace you can see that cmd has stripped away the double quotes.